# Count number of referenced objects in Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given two collections like:

```
users:
    name

posts:
    title
    user_id
```

How can I query for users with more than 5 posts *efficiently*?

I can do an aggregation with `$lookup` but that takes ages for large datasets.

Another option is to maintain a "postCount" on `users` but I would like to avoid having to maintain that.

I'm using Mongoose on Node.

Comment: would you like to get users who has more than 5 post ?

Comment: There is no reason to avoid maintaining a `postCount` field - you could even index it if you are concerned about efficient queries. probably the best way in terms of performance.

Comment: What do you consider "large datasets" and "ages"? Please show your code using `$lookup`. Did you add the relevant indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient aggregate query which uses [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) and a **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline for filtering would be as follows:

```
User.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "posts",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "user_id",
            "as": "posts"
        }
    },
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$gt": [ { "$size": "$posts" }, 5 ] },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, results){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that's fast. This and adding an index on `user_id` did the trick, thanks @str :)